# How to export GridView to excelsheet?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I have a gridview in my page. What I want is when user clicks on the button "Export", it should open a box to download a file and save as a excel sheet. I have pagging enabled in my grid but when I export data, all rows must be sent in the excel sheet irrespective of pagging. I can not export my data source(datatable) because it contains few other columns which are hidden but I am using it just for my purpose and dont what to show it to the users.
How can I do so....??? I am not getting any Idea...

As James Johnson said..I did like that. This is the code given by him

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";

    System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);

    GridView1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);//Error is thrown from here.

    Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

But doing this throws following error at from at specified potion in code

```
Control 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ViewAdvances1_grdAdvance' of type 'GridView' must be  placed inside a form tag with runat=server.
```

I have placed gridview in usercontrol, the usercontrol is placed in .aspx page and that page uses master page which already have form tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    Response.Clear();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.Charset = "";

    System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);

    GridView1.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);

    Response.Write(oStringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: ..Your code shows this error "Control 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ViewAdvances1_grdAdvance' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server." but my grid is placed in content place holder of child page. Master page already have form tag....

Answer (score 0):

It's a lot of discussions regarding this:

[export gridview rows to excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237808/export-gridview-rows-to-excel-sheet)

[Export GridView to Excel](http://mattberseth.com/blog/2007/04/export_gridview_to_excel_1.html)

[Export gridview into excel in Windowsformsapplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401067/export-gridview-into-excel-in-windowsformsapplication) (maybe some useful info you will find here)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your code behind:

```
Public Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)
    'dont delete - needed for excel export
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for export to excel in master page.

**put this code after page load code**

```
 public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)<br/>
    {<br/>
        /* Verifies that the control is rendered */<br/>
        //base.VerifyRenderingInServerForm(control);
    }
```

then

```
protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)<br/>
    {<br/>
        try<br/>
        {<br/>
            BindReportdata(ddlReport.SelectedIndex);<br/>
            Response.Clear();<br/>
            Response.Buffer = true;<br/>
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",<br/>
             "attachment;filename=report.xls");<br/>
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";<br/>
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();<br/>
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);<br/>
            for (int i = 0; i < gv_ReportData.Rows.Count; i++)<br/>
            {
                GridViewRow row = gv_ReportData.Rows[i];<br/>
            }
            gv_ReportData.GridLines = GridLines.Both;<br/>
            gv_ReportData.RenderControl(hw);<br/>
            Response.Write(sw.ToString());<br/>
            Response.Flush();<br/>
            Response.End();<br/>
        }<br/>
        catch (Exception ex)<br/>
        {<br/>
            throw ex;<br/>
        }<br/>
    }<br/>
```

**and in aspx page use  updatepanel and trigger for button**